# Apache server randomly stops service on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2

I can successfully start the apache service, and my websites all work fine. After browsing a few pages, though, the service just stops. To avoid this, I've set a watch to start the service every 2 seconds. This, however, causes problems for when users are downloading large files - as it produces an error in the browser. I have no other services running on ports 80 or 443. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a problem wit insufficient RAM? Have you enabled swap space?

Comment: RAM is plentiful. SWAP is enabled. Barely 1GB of 12GB is being used, and the SWAP is completely empty.

Comment: Without any idea of your apache version, apache configuration, question cannot be answered. Please explain those first.

Comment: Apache version 2.4.18
Apache config: https://my-cdn02.tk/apache2.conf

The configuration is near bone stock.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the

> dmesg

command.

If you see:

[26509757.351826] Out of memory: Kill process 10467 (apache2) score 77 or sacrifice child

You can be sure the OS killed your process due to lack of resources.

I've also seen Apache fail to restart after a log rotation, which is caused by the logrotate command.